# How to use inner feeling (intuitive feeling) while taking refuge

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, meditation, meditation-practicalities, tibetan-buddhism

Starting ngondro practice, taking refuge in 3 jewels. As we know most of the Tibetan schools use the pretty common attitude. So if we are not talking about the differences, but the inner feeling and its development during each stage of the practice. What are they? Could somebody experienced walk us through it or refer to relevant text?

Please try to avoid general answer - there is already plenty information in the literature.
This question is about the essential experience which I consider as the key of the successful practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "inner feeling" mean "insight"?

Comment: I think you're saying (when you said, "not talking about the differences") that it's probably more-or-less the same answer for every Tibetan school -- and/but that you *are* asking a question about, specifically, Tibetan Buddhism.

Answer (score 1):

Taking refuge in the Three Jewels means to make effort to receive the blessings of Buddha, making effort to put Dharma into practice in our daily life and making effort to receive help from our Sangha community and in particular our teachers. 
Blessings are anything that transforms our mind from negative to positive, that increase  our faith etc. A great way to do this is to remember that we are always in the presence of living, loving Buddha. 
There are a myriad of ways to put Dharma into practice such as simply being mindful of a verse of the teachings that has touched our hearts, developing equanimity and love, practicing patience, giving etc. 
Taking positive advice and encouragement from our Dharma brothers and sisters and considering advice from our teacher helps with the last one. Also, seeking to clarify confusion by discussing and debating are good too.